# Alt Key for insert button in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, alt

I am trying to create an <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key for the insert button in my StackPanel, however it's not working.

I have the following code

```
    <StackPanel Name="ButtonsStackPanel" Grid.Row="2">
        <Button Name="btnAnother" Click="btnAnother_Click" Height="24" Width="251" Content="_More" ToolTip="Alt + M"></Button>
        <Button Name="btnInsert" Click="btnInsert_Click" Height="24" Width="251" Content="_Insert" ToolTip="Alt + I"></Button>
        <Button Height="23" Name="btnClose" Width="249" Click="btnClose_Click" ToolTip="Alt + C" Content="_Close"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

For the `More` and `Close` buttons, their <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Key works

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce this.

The key combination is likely to be used by your context which overrides that button's access key combination.

Comment: Hi H.B.  You mean I am using ALT + I somewhere else in that screen?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean. You can try running that code in a clean project, the accessors will work for all buttons.